# Assign the text of an element as a php variable

Tags: php

i have a text inside an element. This text will changed according to a jQuery. As it changes, I need to pull that text as a php variable. This variable will be used later in the same document.

```
<div id="divId">sometext<div>
```

now, I want to assign a php code to assign "sometext" as the variable

I need the below;

```
    <div id="divId">
    sometext
    <?php
    $variable = (get text from "divId");
    ?>
    <div>
```

then I can use it somewhere else like

```
<div>
<?php
if($variable == "sometext")
{
echo ($variable);
}
?>
<div>
```

I need help on the `(get text from "divId")`part

Comment: Once the PHP is sent to the client, PHP no longer has any control.  You'll have to use Javascript to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do with `PHP`. please use `javascript` or `jquery`

please find way of `jquery`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var getDivValue = $('#divId').html();
    if(getDivValue == 'sometext'){
        $('#divId').html('updateText');
    }else if(getDivValue == 'other'){
         $('#divId').html('updateTextTwo');
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divId">sometext</div>

</body>
</html>
```